# My reducer does not seem to modify the state in the store to allow my React view to render again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, ecmascript-next

To begin, I should mention that I have followed this pattern I'm about to show you with two other sets of React components in my project.

For some reason it seems to not work and I have focused in on that either the `@connect` or the reducer is the problem. I've had several people look over this and I've attempted several different methods to solve this problem.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import SidebarMixin from 'global/jsx/sidebar_component';

import Header from 'common/header';
import Sidebar from 'common/sidebar';
import Footer from 'common/footer';
import AppList from '../components/lists';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import actions from 'redux/actions';
import { VisibilityFilters } from 'redux/actions/actionTypes';

@connect((state) => state)
  class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getUnconsidered(1));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getConsidered(3));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getInterviews(4));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getOffers(2));
  }
```

This right here is dispatching four actions to fetch data for the application. We are using Redux Thunk middleware to deal with the async problems associated with making these Ajax requests.

I have found that the data from all of these Ajax calls is reaching the reducer.

```
render() {

console.log("AppContainer state", this.props);
```

This console.log should log twice... once empty during the first render and again when the state changes after the reducers which should show the state with my data mapped to the props because of the `@connect`.

I'm fairly certain of this because of my other views that I've done.

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Container id='body'>
          <Grid>
            <Row>
              <Col md={3}>
                <AppList data={this.props.unconsidered}/>
              </Col>
              <Col md={3}>
                <AppList data={this.props.considered} />
              </Col>
              <Col md={3}>
                <AppList data={this.props.interviews} />
              </Col>
              <Col md={3}>
                <AppList data={this.props.offers} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
         </Grid>
       </Container>
     </div>
     )
   }
 }

@SidebarMixin
export default class extends React.Component {
render() {
const dispatch = this.props.dispatch
    var classes = classNames({
        'container-open': this.props.open
    })
    return (
        <Container id='container' className={classes}>
            <Sidebar />
            <Header />
            <AppContainer />
            <Footer />
        </Container>
    )}
   }
```

This next code block is my action creator file.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {GET_UNCONSIDERED,
              GET_CONSIDERED,
              GET_INTERVIEWS,
              GET_OFFERS } from './actionTypes';

function getUnconsidered(jobID){
    console.log('getUnconsidered Actions')
    return dispatch => axios.get('/user/employer/appsbystatus?jobID='+jobID+'&status=unconsidered')
        .then(
            payload => dispatch({ type: GET_UNCONSIDERED, payload})
        )
        .catch(resp => console.log("Error fetching unconsidered", resp));
}

function getConsidered(jobID){
    return dispatch => axios.get('/user/employer/appsbystatus?jobID='+jobID+'&status=considered')
        .then(
            payload => dispatch({ type: GET_CONSIDERED, payload})
        );
}

function getInterviews(jobID){
    return dispatch => axios.get('/user/employer/appsbystatus?jobID='+jobID+'&status=interviews')
        .then(
            payload => dispatch({ type: GET_INTERVIEWS, payload})
        );
}

function getOffers(jobID){
    return dispatch => axios.get('/user/employer/appsbystatus?jobID='+jobID+'&status=offers')
        .then(
            payload => dispatch({ type: GET_OFFERS, payload})
        );
    }

module.exports = {
    getUnconsidered: getUnconsidered,
    getConsidered: getConsidered,
    getInterviews: getInterviews,
    getOffers: getOffers
}
```

This here is my reducer file and where I believe my problem lies.

```
import {GET_UNCONSIDERED,
          GET_CONSIDERED,
          GET_INTERVIEWS,
          GET_OFFERS } from '../actions/actionTypes';


function empdashboard(state = {}, action) {
    console.log("state in dashboard reducer = ", state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_UNCONSIDERED:
            console.log("unconsidered:", action.payload)
            const unconsidered = action.payload.data;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                unconsidered: unconsidered
            });
        case GET_CONSIDERED:
            console.log("considered:", action.payload)
            const considered = action.payload.data;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                considered: considered
            });
        case GET_INTERVIEWS:
            console.log("interviews:", action.payload)
            const interviews = action.payload.data;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                interviews: interviews
            });
        case GET_OFFERS:
            console.log("offers:", action.payload)
            const offers = action.payload.data;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                offers: offers
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    empdashboard: empdashboard
}
```

Honestly I'm under the impression that either my reducer is messed up or I'm having a bug with my `@connect` and it is not detecting the change in state to rerender my view.

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially the *minimal* part. Your question becomes much easier to answer once you've removed the unnecessary code.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Is the `console.log` in your reducer logging correctly with the correct action type?

Comment: It is logging correctly. Also for every new console.log because there are 4 requests. The "state in dashboard reducer" logs the previous state correctly. For instance when the GET_CONSIDERED case fires, right before that the state has the unconsidered data in it.